# UICollectionViewCell properties are returning null

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uicollectionview

I am having trouble with accessing a property in a collection view cell. When the GetCell method is performed i check with break points and the item is adding to the cell variable with all the correct data which is perfect. However when i then perform the ItemHighlighted event the `cell.item` is null.

I have tried `RegisterClassForCell`, however this causes none of the cells to be visible when the app runs.

```
ExistingEvaluationsCollection.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(ExistingEvaluationCell), ExistingEvaluationCell.CellId);
ExistingEvaluationsCollection.Source = source;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to dequeue the cell in your `ItemHighlighted` method. To get reference to the cell just call the `GetCell` method.

Comment: i got it working by changing the `DequeueReusableCell` to `CellForItem(indexPath);`